# Enforcing a vector function to have symmetric Jacobian matrix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, jacobian

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ be smooth with non-vanishing gradient and define $n: \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ by
$$n(x)=\nabla f(x)/\|\nabla f(x) \|.$$
Let $J_n(x)$ be the Jacobian matrix of $n$.

**Question**
Does there exist a smooth real-valued function $v:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ such that the vector function
$$Z(x) = (J_n(x)+v(x)I)n(x)$$
has a symmetric Jacobian matrix, i.e.
$$\frac{\partial Z^i}{\partial x_j} = \frac{\partial Z^j}{\partial x_i}?$$

**Context/Examples**
Here $M=f^{-1}(\{0\})$ defines a smooth manifold and $P=I-nn^T$ is the orthogonal projection onto the tangent space of $M$. We wish to find scalar function $p$ such that
$$P(x) \nabla \log p(x) = J_n(x) n(x).$$
Note that $P$ leaves the RHS unchanged, so that
$$\nabla \log p(x) -J_n(x) n(x)$$
must be in the kernel of $P$ which is equal to the span of $\nabla f$. Thus,
$$\nabla \log p(x) =J_n(x)n(x) + c \nabla f(x).$$
For some scalar $c$. Let’s assume this is actually a scalar function, in the form $c = v(x)/\|\nabla f(x)\|$ so that we can rewrite the last displayed equation as
$$\nabla \log p(x) = [J_n(x) +v(x)I]n(x)=: Z(x)$$
and for the RHS to be a potential we need the “curl free” condition written above regarding the partials. So we wish to choose $v(x)$ such that this condition holds.

For the ellipse and ellipsoid, I have guessed solutions $p$ which satisfy $P\nabla \log p = J_n n$ so that I then could back out $v(x)$ (I can typeset these when I’m back at my desk later) but unfortunately I have not found a direct way of constructing or finding $v$ to then recover $p$ through gradient integration. Any help is appreciated, and please comment for corrections or clarifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We will show that if we add a multiple of $n$ to $J_n(n)$, then it is a gradient of some function. (Automatically, symmetric Jacobian matrix is followed).

Proof : Define $$ H = {\rm ln}\ |\nabla f|^2 $$ where $
  \nabla f =f_i E_i, \ f_i=E_i(f)$ and $E_i = \frac{\partial }{
  \partial x_i}$

Hence $E_q (H)=\frac{2\sum_i f_i f_{iq} }{|\nabla f|^2} $ so that
$$ \nabla H = 2 {\rm Hess}\ (f)(n) \frac{1}{|\nabla f|} $$ where ${\rm Hess} (f) $
is a Hessian matrix of a function $f$.

Here note that $J_n(n) = n(n)$ so that \begin{align*}
  n(n) &= \frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|} ( \frac{
  \nabla f}{|\nabla f|} )
  \\& = \frac{1}{H} f_i f_{ij}E_j +
   \frac{1}{|\nabla f|} \nabla f (e^{-\frac{1}{2} H } ) \nabla f \\
   &  = {\rm Hess}\ (f)(n) \frac{1}{|\nabla f|} +
   \nabla f(e^{-\frac{1}{2} H} ) n \end{align*}

Hence $$ n(n) - \nabla f(e^{-\frac{1}{2} H} )n = \frac{1}{2}
   \nabla H $$

Comment: Apologies but may you clarify the notation/equation $J_n(n)=n(n)$? If I interpret it as $J_n(n(x)) =n(n(x))$ for any $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$, then I am confused because $J_n(x)$ is a $d\times d$ matrix with $i,j$-entry given by $\frac{\partial n^i}{\partial x_j}(x)$ but $n(n(x))$ is simply a vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$. What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: I mean the following notation : If $X,\ Y$ are vector fields on $
\mathbb{R}^d$, then $X(Y)=\sum_i X(Y_i)E_i$ where $Y=\sum_i Y_iE_i$.


Hence $n(n) = \sum_{i,j}n_i E_i(n_j) E_j$ where $n=\sum_i n_iE_i$.


Since $J_n$ is a Jacobian of the vector $n$, then the entry
$(J_n)_{ij}=E_j( n_i)$ which implies that $$n(n)= \sum_{i,j} n_j
(J_n)_{ij} E_i = J_n (n) $$ where $J_n(n)$ is a matrix
multiplication.

Comment: I apologize I was busy the past couple days and missed the chance to award you the bounty. I’ll start a new one and reward it soon.